# Reading FIFOs, resource temporary unavailable

Tags: c, multithreading, fifo

I have a problem with a multithreaded program.
Basically I'm using fifos to pass messages between threads

This is the thread that read from the pipe:

```
thread_args args = (thread_args) *arguments;
char* fifo_buffer = calloc (FIFO_SIZE, sizeof(char));
int flag;
int fifo_win_to_send = open(args.fifo_names[FIFO_WTS], O_RDONLY);
if (fifo_win_to_send < 0) {
    perror("fifo: error opening fifo");
    exit(1);
}

flag = fcntl(fifo_win_to_send, F_GETFL);
fcntl(fifo_win_to_send, F_SETFL, flag | O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY);

if (read( fifo_win_to_send, fifo_buffer, FIFO_SIZE) <= 0) {
            perror("fifo: error reading window to sender fifo");
            exit(1);
}
if (VERBOSE_SENDER) {
            printf("Read %s from fifo window_to_sender", fifo_buffer);
            fflush(stdout);
}
```

and the "writing thread":

```
char * fifo_buffer = calloc(FIFO_SIZE, sizeof(char));
thread_args args = (thread_args) *arguments;
int fifo_win_to_send = open(args.fifo_names[FIFO_WTS], O_WRONLY);
    if (fifo_win_to_send < 0) {
        perror("fifo: error opening fifo");
        exit(1);
    }

*fifo_buffer = 'A';
memcpy(fifo_buffer+1, &sequence_number, sizeof(int));
write( fifo_win_to_send, fifo_buffer, FIFO_SIZE);
if (VERBOSE_FIFO) {
    printf("From window to send:%s\n", fifo_buffer);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The fifo files are created in the main() before threads are spawned:

```
mkdir("temp",0777);
char * fifo_id[6];
for(i=0;i<6;i++)  {
    fifo_id[i]=calloc(100,sizeof(char));
}
fifo_id[FIFO_WTS] = strcpy(fifo_id[FIFO_WTS], "temp/window_to_sender");
if(mkfifo(fifo_id[FIFO_WTS], 0777)) {
    if(errno!=EEXIST) {
        perror("fifo: Cannot create named pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The error occours running the program when trying to read from the fifo. The console reads "fifo: error reading window to sender fifo: Resource temporarily unavailable" the read should be "non blocking" but I've no idea if it's correct or what seems to be the problem. (first time trying to use both threads and fifos so I may have made sort of a mess...)

Comment: Why did you set non-blocking mode?  If you do, and there is no data to read yet, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: the read is under a loop in the actual program, i expect to move on and check later if there is data

Comment: OK, then do so!  If the read fails, check errno and, if it's EAGAIN, carry on doing other stuff and try the read later.

Comment: thanks I totally missed the significance of EAGAIN in the use of non-blocking FIFOs

Answer (score 4):

I think i found the problem.
Since is non blocking when there is no data returns the error EAGAIN, so writing something like

```
if (read( fifo_win_to_send, fifo_buffer, FIFO_SIZE) <= 0 && errno != EAGAIN) {
            perror("fifo: error reading window to sender fifo");
            exit(1);
}
```

fixes the problem!